# created modified function (default) is not working in Cakephp 1.2 version

Tags: cakephp

I created an application and all the db tables have 'created,modified' fields that filled automatically by Cakephp's Default Functionality.
And I put the Field Type is

```
created datetime NULL,
modified datetime NULL,
```

like.
But it doesn't work. The data where shows `0000-00-00 00:00:00` Format.

The cakephp version is 1.2 , so i put the datetime NULL option ,also I removed the temp,cache files in Model.

I need to save the correct date & time format for those 2 fields.

If there is any problem with XAMPP version (I use the latest version of XAMPP,1.7.7 PHP: 5.3.8 & mysql v 5.5.16 )

I hope that all are identifies my Issue.
Please help me with correct solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a similar issue but in CakePHP 2.1.3 with the created and modified columns inserting a bunch of zeros instead of the current datetime.

My problem was the existing cache of the relevant model. I had to delete the existing model cache to make this automatic datetime stuff work. The cache be found in: app/tmp/cache/models/.

I think I had this problem in the first place because I altered the structure of the table after its initial creation, adding the created field.

After deleting the model cache once, it was was working fine.

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear from your post; but you need to set the default value to be `null` as well as setting the field to null (always confused me):

```
ALTER TABLE `your_table` CHANGE `created` `created` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL
```

and

```
ALTER TABLE `your_table` CHANGE `modified` `modified` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL
```

Then try clearing the cache files and add a new record.

Comment: Thank you for the reply,I Already add The Same for each  tables. Here Table fields, created , modified had set to                                                               created datetime NULL,
modified datetime NULL, But the data stored here as         0000-00-00 00:00:00. But the code is not working.

Comment: The above solution will work, but you don't need to set the created field to NULL. You can have it as NOT NULL and Cake will still automatically insert the date. The only thing you have to be careful of is to make sure that there is no default value at all. As long as there is no default value, it will work properly, NULL or NOT NULL

Comment: DEFAULT NULL is the recommended approach, though, to avoid invalid zero dates @Joseph